# How to make in bootstrap a input with only 1 character width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a Soccer Bet app.

I'm using React and bootstrap and now I'm stuck in a apparently simple problem.

I want to make a input for the bets (in soccer the matches always are lower than 3 digits). How can I make a input with a fixed size of 2 characters in bootstrap?

My screen, for example, will have home and away teams, and 2 inputs with the desirable bet of the user like:

BRAZIL [] x [] GERMANY.

These inputs needs to have a fixed size of 2.

Thanks

Comment: it's more of validation issue.

Answer (score 1):

If this is to make sure your inputs only accept 2 characters max then use the maxlength attribute.

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="2" />
```

If you are talking about styling (making a small input sin you mentioned bootsrap) then this is a completely different story.

You can do something like:

```
<form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="brazil">BRAZIL</label>
 <input type="text" id="brazil" class="form-control form-control-sm small-input" />
X
 <input type="text" id="germany" class="form-control form-control-sm small-input" />
 <label for="germany">GERMANY</label>
</div> 
</form>
```

And size to fit your needs like:

```
.small-input {
 width: 5px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0byt7cbu/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the max length attribute in HTML

`<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`